# Audio Segment Library in Python Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg, telegram-bot

I need to use the Audio Segment Library to Convert Audios to Text I install it but it's showing a Warning at runtime whaen I Run the Project and it doesn't work:

> RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
> warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)

```
sound = AudioSegment.from_ogg('user.ogg')
        sound.export('user.wav', format="wav")
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.AudioFile("user.wav") as source:
            audio = r.record(source)
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(text)
```

> Note: It was working before I format my computer ,But when I try to reinstall it ,The Message Appears.

I need Your Kindly help
and Thank You...

Comment: The warning message says it all. Have you checked if the tools are on your PATH?

Comment: Hello @LukaszTracewski
Thanks for Supporting..
which tool you mean ffmeg?
I tried to install it but I didn't know how to use it it is like a file not installation

Comment: Yes, make sure you have both `ffmpeg` and `avconv` on your PATH so that Python can use the executables. If you don't know what I am talking about, lookup how to set PATH for your OS and later check from the command line that you can run these tools.

Comment: thank you @LukaszTracewski I will try this method 
I know how to add it to the path

Comment: thank you it works i was installing the code of ffmpeg not the .exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the ffmpeg page, don't choose the option to download the code. Instead, choose to install the .exe file. Once done, you will see ffmpeg.exe in the bin folder inside the ffmpeg folder. Finally, put the path of the bin folder into the PATH system/user variable.